# Correct database design for JPA entity inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I'm starting a new project using JPA 2 + Hibernate 4.2.6 for data access.

I have two tables in my DB representing two different kinds of `Answer`, so I have `answer_type_a` and `answer_type_b` tables.
The are identical except for one field.

Now I'm creating my model classes and I'd like to inherit my `AnswerA` and `AnswerB` entities from a commom super-class or interface `Answer`.

I read some docs about entity inheritance:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html
- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass

but I have not a clear view on how to structure my DB and my entity classes to achieve this. Can you help me?

Comment: Wich version of JPA and Hibernate you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need table `Answer` - that is super for particular others, where you should place all common columns for `answer_type_a` and `answer_type_b`. Assume `Answer.a_id` is primary key, then  `answer_type_a.a_id` `answer_type_b.a_id` are simultaneously PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY.

Of course don't forget to place distinguished columns to `answer_type_a` and `answer_type_b`

```
+---------+
| Answer  |
+---------+       ----------------------->--+--------------+
| a_id    +------)                          | answer_type_b|
                  ---->-+--------------+    +--------------+ 
  ...                   | answer_type_a|    | a_id         |
                        +--------------+       ...
                        | a_id         |
                           ....
```

Comment: Why should I prefer this approach instead of creating a `@MappedSuperclass` class (avoiding to create a new table in my DB)?

Comment: It strongly depends on amount of information in `answer_type_a` and `answer_type_b`, assume that there are big distinguishes there - then to reduce table overhead you need separate tables. Otherwise use MapperSuperclass or review possibility for discriminator (http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_mapping_discrim.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one class named `Answer` with the common fields and you will annotate it with `@MappedSuperclass`. Additionally, you will have 2 entity classes, named `AnswerA` and `AnswerB` which will only hold the "extra" fields.

If you have 2 tables, then you need to use the `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance type. So add `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` to the `Answer` class, and probably a `@Table` annotation to `AnswerA` and `AnswerB`.

But if I were you, I would use one table for all answers, with all the needed columns + one discriminator column so you can distinguish if a row is answer type a or type b.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understand your question is about mapping:

You need a java class `Answer` which is actually your super class. As there is no corresponding DB table for that, it must be annotated with [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Answer {
//fields&properties
}
```

And now the two classes come, which are entities, as they are persisted in DB tables:

```
@Entity
@Table("answer_type_a")
public class AnswerA extends Answer {
  //here you add the field that is not common with AnswerB
}
@Entity
@Table("answer_type_b")
public class AnswerB extends Answer {
  //here you add the field that is not common with AnswerA
}
```

PS: IMHO you don't need any inheritance annotations, as the mapped super class is not an entity.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was in a similar situation like you. The best solution found was using an abstract class as a super type, and extending that class to the concrete types (which will represent your entity).

So for your situation you would model something like this.

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class Answer{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

    @Column
    String commonFieldOne;

    @Column
    String commonFieldTwo;

    @Column
    String commonFieldThree;    
    ...    
}
```

Note that I used the `@MappedSuperClass` annotation. This tells JPA that this is a super class that will not be instantiated and should not have a database table associated with it.
Also note that the `Id` which will serve as the primary key for both child tables is defined in this class

Now for you concrete classes (which will be mapped to tables in you database), you would use the `@Entity` annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table("answer_type_a")
public class AnswerA extends Answer{
   //All common fields from Answer table will be included in the DB tables as columns automatically

    @Column
    String uniqueFieldOne;
    ....

}
```

You can do the same for `@Table("answer_type_b")`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just create one table in your database e.g answer which contains both fields. You must have three classes Class 1 : Answer, Class 2: Answer_Type_A extends Answer, Class 3: Answer_Type_B extends Answer. There will be an hbm file for Answer (superclass) and two hbm for each Answer_Type_A and Answer_Type_B. In sybclass hbm files include:

```
<hibernate-mapping>  <subclass name="com.test.Answer_Type_A" 
    extends="com.test.Answer">
<property name="fieldA" />
</subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```